# Omit entire type in Tyepscript discriminated union

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Discriminated unions are one of the handiest things in typescript. However, they're very difficult to manipulate once defined. The thing I'm trying to figure out is how to omit an entire type in a union. Take the following example:

```js
export type A = {
  type: 'a',
  a: 'a'
}

export type B = {
  type: 'b',
  b: 'b'
}

export type C = A | B;
```

This is all well and good, but is there any way for a consuming module to restrict type C back down to just A?

I want to accomplish something like the following in the consuming module:

```js
import { A, C, B } from 'type-defs.d'

type NewTypeA = SPECIAL_OMIT<C, B>

// A should be equivalent to NewTypeA
```

But I can't figure out any way to do this. Note that I am NOT asking for a way to omit *properties* from the discriminated type. I want to omit the entire type from the union.

Comment: You likely want [`Exclude<C, B>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu)

Comment: You're a genius! Should I answer my own question or what?